# How to get right-to-left words without Arabic locale in wince 6

Tags: windows-ce, right-to-left, arabic-support

I have a device named **Point Mobile PM450** with **WinCE 6** OS that has not Arabic locale. I have copied Arabic fonts like `tahoma.ttf` and `tahomabd.ttf` to `Windows/Fonts` directory. Now Arabic characters are showing but the sentences are not readable because they are left-to-right while Arabic is right-to-left.
For example my word is `سلام` and my device shows `م ا ل س`.

I can't use `Platform Builder` because my company restricted me from editing run-time-image. So I need something like **Arabizer** or **Arabware** or something **compatible with Win CE 6**.

> **Note:** `Arabizer` and `Arabware` are not compatible. The error is `The Application cannot run on this device type. Please install the application specific to this device type.`

I also tried changing registry nodes and replacing 409(English) with 401(Arabic) and I succeed changing layout to right-to-left but the words are yet left-to-right.

StackOverflow restricted me from sending images but here is my device screen shot:

[Sample word file](http://s6.picofile.com/file/8237517268/IMG_20160207_124750.jpg).

Now the question is:

How can I get right-to-left words without Arabic locale in wince 6?

> If anyone needs sample C# class [here it is](http://s6.picofile.com/file/8238617842/Reverse_For_WinCE6.rar.html)
>   (persian site).
>
> It is useful when you have access to the source code but I have not.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot add "Unicode Script Processor for Complex Script" for Arabic via Platform Builder there is no much you can do...
The only thing you can do is to develop a layer in your application for managing arabic text display...

Comment: I told that I have no access to application source code. It should be done somehow in operating system(wince6)

Comment: You told that you cannot edit run time wince image. Now you say that you don't have access also to application source code... I think you cannot achieve your result...

Comment: Dear @salvolds please read my last line in second yellow box. In Windows Mobile we have **Arabware** that adds Arabic locale including Persian characters. In this thread I asked something like that. **Arabware** is an install-able setup to extend operating system options.

Comment: Dear @Mostafa, also if you asked for something like Arabware in the body of your question, as you can read your final question was "How can I get right-to-left words without Arabic locale in wince 6?". My answer was to this generic question... 
Then you add details to your question using these comments with an unmotivated polemic tone... Anyway, if your final question is for something like arabware then I cannot help you.

Comment: Dear @salvolds I think you used **unmotivated polemic tone**. I'm sorry if you think it was me. Anyway please read questions correctly then write comment or answer if you think you can help. Again if you are upset for my words **excuse me my friend**.